# Cypress - test crashes if cy.task errors out/crashes and not moving to the next test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have around 10 spec files and each of the spec files has around 5 to 7 tests each.
Each of the test invokes a cy.task and do some operations. If cy.task fails ( I mean if there is an exception ) , the whole of the test gets crashed and I am not able to move to the next test within the spec file.

Cypress just moves to the next spec file. But even the test in the next spec file is not running. It just gets stuck there for infinity.

I am able to catch the exception but cypress crashes there.

Any idea how to handle plugin crash scenario and move on to the next test ( basically next it block ) in Cypress ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you got the gold to get rid of the crash? I am currently getting it.